# Generating TIN from elevation data in Java

Tags: java, tin

I would like to generate TIN from standard elevation data in Java. Are there any libraries I can use? I could not find any just by googling. In addition library should be suitable for commercial use and has to have no native dependencies.

Other option is me writing a library that does the job. For that, can you suggest a good source that explains the algorithm clearly.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Unfortunately, you have two questions here, and both of them are *opinion-based*/recommendation-list oriented. In general, GIS SE is not that useful for primary research, since its focus is on specific problems and their answers. Stack Exchange has a [softwarerecs.se] site for recommendations; you should of course read their tour before posting there.